# How to use docker toolbox with hadoop streaming to solve map reduce with multi node cluster

Tags: docker, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I am able to use a single node to solve a map reduce problem using docker. But now for multinode I need to link with another PC. How can I get the IP address of other computers that are my slave nodes inside the docker container? As far as I know, the IP address in the docker machine is the same for every computer: `192.168.99.100`

Comment: You may want to update your title to better reflect your actual question. You will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The title and your question don't seem to match. Are you trying to determine the IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested to run docker on Windows, and the image `sequenceiq/hadoop-docker` is not well designed for multi nodes. You'd better deploy your cluster on Linux.

To resolve the ip of other containers, use hostname rather than ip (as they may change if not specified). One way to do that is use docker swarm.

Here is some simple steps to deploy a distributed Hadoop cluster.

First of all, you need to create a docker swarm by `docker swarm init` in the master node, and add other nodes to the swarm by coping & executing the command.

Then, create an overlay network by `docker network create --driver overlay swarm-net`.

To build a cluster with one master and three slaves.

```sh
docker service create \
    --name hadoop-master \
    --network swarm-net \
    --hostname hadoop-master \
    --replicas 1 \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    newnius/hadoop:2.7.4

docker service create \
    --name hadoop-slave1 \
    --network swarm-net \
    --hostname hadoop-slave1 \
    --replicas 1 \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    newnius/hadoop:2.7.4

docker service create \
    --name hadoop-slave2 \
    --network swarm-net \
    --hostname hadoop-slave2 \
    --replicas 1 \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    newnius/hadoop:2.7.4

docker service create \
    --name hadoop-slave3 \
    --network swarm-net \
    --hostname hadoop-slave3 \
    --replicas 1 \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    newnius/hadoop:2.7.4
```

And then format the namenode, start YARN.

```sh
# stop all Hadoop processes
sbin/stop-yarn.sh
sbin/stop-dfs.sh

# format namenode
bin/hadoop namenode -format

# start yarn and dfs nodes
sbin/start-dfs.sh
sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

But note that, this way you cannot browse the WebUI directly.

You can find a full document here

https://blog.newnius.com/how-to-quickly-setup-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker.html (for experiment use)

https://blog.newnius.com/setup-distributed-hadoop-cluster-with-docker-step-by-step.html (for production use, including exposing the UI & HDSF outside the swarm)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering me.So if my docker toolbox is running in virtualized linux instance eg inside virtual box with Window as host os also cannot? Isn't you meant I have to install linux in virtual box then install docker?

Comment: Hi which images can u recommend for solving multi node cluster hadoop map reduce? thanksss in advance

Comment: You can form a cluster in virtual box, but you have to configure the network to make them reachable / in the same network (NAT adapter).

Comment: https://cloud.docker.com/u/newnius/repository/docker/newnius/hadoop You can use this image which is originally built for cluster use.

Comment: Thankss, isnt okay that I conitnue to use my docker toolbox running in virtualized linux instead of installing linux ?

Comment: If i want to form cluster with different PC instead of running different node in the same PC isn't okay? sorry for asking too many question i would be much appreciate if you can answer me thankss.

Comment: There is no difference whether you use multi physical machines or virtualbox machines as long as you configure the network properly.

Comment: Thanks so isn't okay that I continue to use my docker toolbox running in virtualized linux instead of installing linux ?

Comment: I got this error when I execute the command to other machine even though i update the hostfile with the ip address and hostnames.                                                  
                                                                                                                     
 "Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error:connection error:desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192:168:99:100:2377: connect: connection refused".

Comment: You have to make sure that VM a and VM b can connect to each other. Be default, virtualbox machines can only connect to the Internet and cannot be accessed from teh host machine.

Comment: Sorry I am totally new in IT. Actually how to make them connect? I tried many ways to connect both different docker machine running in different PC but failed. And I have few question here first is                                                                                                               1)When I ipconfig on both my PC(2 diff physical machine). They hv the same IP address the difference is the IPv4 address so when I update my hostfile for each machine can i use the IPv4 address with their hostname?

Comment: 2)Actually i need to update my hostfile in ssh or just in docker toolbox and do I need to open ports on the firewall?                                                                   Sorry for asking too many question.Hope you can help me thankss

Comment: If the two PCs are one the same network, then you must be wrong as they cannot be assigned the same ip. Connect them to the same network (WI-FI or else) and make sure they have dirrerent ip address and use `ping 192.168.xxx.xxx` to confirm thay can connect to each other. By default, Ubuntu doesn't block traffic but CentOS would, so you'd better disable that. As to Windows, I don't know whether it would accept the traffic.

Comment: Yes they are in a same wifi network so that's mean i should use the wifi ip which is 10.212.xxx.xxx. I tried also to create a node in my virtual box on one of my PC I got a different ip which is 192.xxx.xx.101 for that node. But if two different PC the ip is same which is 192.168.99.100.So I am confused which ip to choose since I want to form cluster with different PC.

Comment: I followed this [link] (https://blog.newnius.com/setup-distributed-hadoop-cluster-with-docker-step-by-step.html). But when I join to other worker i keep getting error connection refused. Before i join my worker I should update my hostfile in ssh or docker command shell?

Comment: You network seems complicated. If you just want to run MRs in distributed mode for learning MR, I advice you to use only one machine/virtual machine.

Comment: This is the guide to do that with docker swarm: https://blog.newnius.com/how-to-quickly-setup-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker.html

Comment: And if you have to the requirements to run really big data, then you'd better install Linux rather than Windows as there may be incredible questions.

Comment: Thanksss i will try to use one machine but will it be any problem if my PC RAM is just 4gb.

Comment: I should set my network in virtualbox to NAT or internal network? in order to make both my virtual machine connect. Currently my adapter1 is NAT while adapter2 is host-only adapter

Comment: It is not that easy to connect two vms on different phusical machines. 4gb ram is kind of small for Hadoop, not sure if this would operate properly. And I have recorded a video for this https://youtu.be/DojzlG5bO3k should be available several hours later

Comment: BTW, if you're a student, you can apply for GitHub student packs in https://education.github.com/pack which contains $50 credit from digitocean. Then you can create larger VMs, say 8G/16G

Comment: Ohh great thanks for the info. If i use digitalocean it still able to read my files from my local machine and put at hdfs right as the mapper and reducer i code in python file and also all the files to perform map reduce are in my local c drive.

Comment: It is just like a virtualbox machine. You can treat them as seperated physical machines. Just upload your files to them by scp or other tools (FileZilla sftp).